# System is computationally singular error in R

Tags: r, statistics

I'm doing Zero-Inflated Model to my data. I'm using RStudio and `pscl` package. My models:

```
z_deniz <- zeroinfl(YANs ~ deniz, dist = "poisson", link = "logit", data=zipveri3)
zn3_nufus05 <- zeroinfl(YANs ~ nufus05, dist = "negbin", link = "logit", data=zipveri3)
```

I don't have problems with my other models but I get this error with these two models:

> Error in solve.default(as.matrix(fit$hessian)) : 
>         system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 9.93413e-121

Dependent variable is fire counts and independent variables are distance to coastline and population. I tried to log transform my dependent variable but it didn't work.

```
summary(regveri3$deniz)
     Min.   1st Qu.    Median      Mean   3rd Qu.      Max. 
     4.24  18010.00  48070.00  65760.00  97340.00 269200.00
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Please add some data to make this a MWE. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/28481250?s=3|0.0000#28481250

Comment: I think this is more of a *math* question than a *programming* question: see http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/76488/error-system-is-computationally-singular-when-running-a-glm and http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/71438/computationally-singular-error-using-mirt-package (and more at [CrossValidated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=computationally+singular+[r])).

Answer (score 1):

Try specifying the regressors for the zero component. If you want to use none,
then add "1"; otherwise replace "1" with the variables you want to use:

```
z_deniz <- zeroinfl(YANs ~ deniz | 1, dist = "poisson", link = "logit", data=zipveri3)
```

Source can be found [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/pscl/versions/1.4.9/topics/zeroinfl) .